# Strange behavior when exucuting .exe file created with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have created the following program in Python.

```
import os
import urllib.request
import random

def prim():
    print('do you want to download image? (y\\n) \n')
    b=input()
    if b =="y":
        tal()

def letzdown(url):
    num=random.randrange(0,1000)
    name=str(num)+'.jpeg'
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\amal\\Desktop\\python downloaded images')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,name)
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\amal\\PycharmProjects\\untitled')

''' directory directing'''

def tal():
    print('Enter the image url \n')
    a=input()
    letzdown(a)
    prim()

prim()
exit()
```

Afterwards I created a .exe file from .py file using pyinstaller. When I try to execute the .exe file screen just flashes and nothing happens.how can i fix this?

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Nothing understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Your script might be throwing error and the command line is closed immediately. To keep the command line open even after execution and view the error, open the folder in which your exe file exist and then try shift + right click, and select the option '*Open Command window here*'. Drag exe file here and execute. Now after execution, the command window will not be closed and you can verify the error or results.